# How to make a JButton fill his parent BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(400, 300);
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {{
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    add(new JButton("button"));
    add(new JTextField("Text"));
}};

frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I want to make JButton fill parent layout like JTextField. So what property controlled it?

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` or if your prefer something which will continue to honour the width of the button, a `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make JButton fill parent layout like JTextField. So what property controlled it?

`BoxLayout` respects the "maximum size" of the component.

The maximum size of a button is its "preferred size", so if you want the button to grow you need to override the `getMaximumSize()` method of the button to return a dimension at least the size of your frame.

Or as is mentioned in the comments you can use:

1. a `GridLayout` to make all components the same size
2. a `GridBagLayout` to allow components to grow as required.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `BorderLayout` for a quick solution.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
add(new JButton("button"),BorderLayout.WEST);
add(new JTextField("Text"),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

this should work for you